# I am a beginner. Should I answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, participation

I'm not a professional programmer, but I have some experience. Sometimes I see a question, but I'm not sure about the answer, or even if I am confident. I'm not an advanced programmer and my answer can be bad, or worse, **so** should I answer questions or not?

And about asking questions, maybe it’s a good idea to open a branch or site for beginners. I don’t like to bother people with my stupid beginner questions, but there I will be able to ask my questions without being voted down, and professional programmers who want to help beginners in their first steps, will guide them to be professionals.

Comment: If you're fairly sure answer, I'm sure some questions are within your reach. As for asking, ask away. We have no objection to beginner questions; so long as they are well written (try to make sure they haven't been asked already too)

Comment: Except for bed answer your English is just fine!

Comment: When questions get downvoted, do the users have to provide a reason?  It seems as though some users might downvote an answer simply because they don't like the topic or they are being mean-hearted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! As long as you are reasonably sure in your answer, there is no reason not to. If you edit it carefully and write it well according to the rules, you might get some upvotes.

Even if you get downvoted, as long as you have posted politely and well, the downvotes will serve as a learning experience to learn what was wrong with your code.

As for questions, as the comments have said, as long as your question meets the requirements and is not a duplicate, not answerable directly from documentation (e.g. "What does the map method do in Ruby?"), and is written well, you should be fine.